# Create ECS Task definition error invalid request provided: is not authorized to perform: ecs:RegisterTaskDefinition on resource: *

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I am creating ECS task definition using cloudformation template.
All the required permissions against ecs are given to my user.as shown below

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "ECSManageRole",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "ecs:UpdateTaskSet",
            "ecs:UpdateServicePrimaryTaskSet",
            "ecs:UpdateService",
            "ecs:UpdateContainerInstancesState",
            "ecs:UpdateContainerAgent",
            "ecs:UpdateCapacityProvider",
            "ecs:TagResource",
            "ecs:Submit*",
            "ecs:StopTask",
            "ecs:StartTelemetrySession",
            "ecs:StartTask",
            "ecs:RunTask",
            "ecs:RegisterTaskDefinition",
            "ecs:PutClusterCapacityProviders",
            "ecs:ListTasks",
            "ecs:ListTaskDefinitions",
            "ecs:ListTaskDefinitionFamilies",
            "ecs:ListServices",
            "ecs:ListContainerInstances",
            "ecs:ListClusters",
            "ecs:ExecuteCommand",
            "ecs:DescribeTasks",
            "ecs:DescribeTaskDefinition",
            "ecs:DescribeServices",
            "ecs:DescribeContainerInstances",
            "ecs:DescribeClusters",
            "ecs:DescribeCapacityProviders",
            "ecs:DeregisterTaskDefinition",
            "ecs:DeregisterContainerInstance",
            "ecs:DeleteTaskSet",
            "ecs:DeleteService",
            "ecs:CreateTaskSet",
            "ecs:CreateService",
            "ecs:CreateCapacityProvider"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:XXX:*"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "ECSReadRole",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "ecs:List*",
            "ecs:Describe*"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:XXX:*"
    }
]
```

}

But still getting this error.
(Note: in Write/Read section actions are repeating but should not impact this)

```
ECS Task definition error nvalid request provided: Create TaskDefinition: User: arn:aws:sts::XXX:assumed-role/ADO_ROLE/aws-vsts-tools is not authorized to perform: ecs:RegisterTaskDefinition on resource: * because no identity-based policy allows the ecs:RegisterTaskDefinition action
```

Answer (score -1):

This is because of resources
some actions need Resources "*" [All Resources] instead of Specific resource
We can select All resources for this action & can resolve this issue